# How to Search for a word only in first line of file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

i want to search a word in only first line of file in unix and if word is not present then insert a line before and in the last of the file

for eg

demo.txt file contains

I am looking for something

ABC
DEF
this is demo file

suppose i want to check in first line i am looking for word 'request'
here in this file request is not in first line so a new line before current line should be added

demo.txt should contain now

added request

I am looking for something

ABC
DEF
this is demo file

added request last

Above we can see first and last line are added
any suggestions, i had used sed

code:
[ "$(sed -n '1p' demo.txt)"=="request" ]

but above code does not work

Answer (score 0):

When wanting to automate **ed**iting a file in a script, `ed` is often a better choice than `sed` - especially if you want to write multiple things to multiple different locations, as it's easy to move the current-line cursor around to arbitrary places. Example:

```
$ cat demo.txt
I am looking for something
ABC DEF this is demo file
$ ed -s demo.txt <<'EOF'
1v/request/i\
added request\
.\
$a\
added request last\
.\
w
EOF
$ cat demo.txt
added request
I am looking for something
ABC DEF this is demo file
added request last
```

Translation:

If the first line does not contain the string *request* (`1v/request/`), **i**nsert text before the first line, and **a**ppend text after the last line, and finally **w**rite the changed file back to disk. The backslashes at the end of every line but the last are needed to treat the entire thing as a single list of commands passed to `v`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?
To edit file, just add `-i` option.
GNU sed only.

```
$ cat demo.txt
I am looking for something
ABC DEF this is demo file

$ cat demo2.txt
Blah Blah request Blah
ABC DEF this is demo file

$ sed -n '1{/request/!{h;s/.*/added request/;p;x;}};p;${g;/added request/{s/.*/& last/p}}' demo.txt
added request
I am looking for something
ABC DEF this is demo file
added request last

$ sed -n '1{/request/!{h;s/.*/added request/;p;x;}};p;${g;/added request/{s/.*/& last/p}}' demo2.txt
Blah Blah request Blah
ABC DEF this is demo file
```